# Using fromarray from PIL to save an image vector of 4 channels and then re-reading it

Tags: arrays, image, python-imaging-library

I have an image vector `v` with the `(100, 100, 4)` dimensions. To save this image vector, I used `PIL` as follows.

```
im = Image.fromarray(v)
```

The image vector is not RGB, As it have 4 channels. I got the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

I also got few more errors. I think, there is some issue with the type of my array. The type of `v` vectors is as follows.

```
print(type(v))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get this error if your basic datatype is unacceptable to `Image.fromarray()`. So, for example, it will happily accept an array of unsigned 8-bit integers:

```
i=np.zeros((100,100,4),dtype=np.uint8)   # specify unsigned 8-bit ints

print(i.dtype)                           # prints dtype('uint8')
im = Image.fromarray(i)                  # works fine
```

Now try with unacceptable type:

```
i=np.zeros((100,100,4),dtype=np.int16) 
print(i.dtype)                           # prints dtype('int16')                                                   

im = Image.fromarray(i) 
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

So, the answer is that your underlying datatype is unacceptable. Check it with `v.dtype`.